# Cancel LINQPad program run

Tags: .net, linqpad

Is it possible to cancel long running programs that I run in [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net)? 
If so, how?

Edit:

LINQPad can become unresponsive for a long time when displaying very big objects. Then you either have to wait or kill LINQPad.

This does not happen in general when running programs that run for a long time.

Comment: Downvoters should preferably comment. I can then potentially adjust the question or delete.

Comment: Isn't this question on topic because it directly involves a tool that is primarily used for programming? Just wondering because there is a close vote.

Comment: I think this question is on-topic, but was unclear/under-specified initially. The edit improved it significantly, so I propose to keep it open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience there are two main phases where LINQPad might spend significant time when executing your query:

1. while executing the query against the data context and gathering the data
2. while retrieving and converting the data into the HTML format for display

While LINQPad is executing your query (phase 1 above), you can cancel the query with <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F5</kbd>.

While LINQPad is building the HTML to display, I unfortunately haven't found a way to cancel the query. What I normally do is *either* kill LINQPad (through task manager or other means) completely (since it saves queries automatically, you normally don't lose any work) *or* just let the query run its course. Then I convert my `Dump()` calls to `Dump(0)` to ensure I get results more quickly next time.

It certainly would be nice if LINQPad would do a breadth-first approach before expanding to deeper dump levels. Pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F5</kbd> could in that case simply stop expanding at whatever level it had reached. If you agree, it might be a good enhancement to request on [LINQPad's UserVoice](https://linqpad.uservoice.com/forums/18302-linqpad-feature-suggestions) site.

Comment: This should now be fixed in LINQPad - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/24403799/46223  Let me know how you get on.

Answer (score 2):

Press <kbd>Shift + F5</kbd> to stop the running program. Or from the menu

Query ->Cancel

Comment: It didn't seem to work. I sometimes accidentally Dump() large objects. The program seems to be unresponsive for some time then.

Comment: I tested with a sleep, `Thread.Sleep(1000000)` it works. Not that `Dump` is different, `Dump` takes time means LinqPad is working on, not the program you wrote. So Linqpad itself busy, it can't handle user shortcut keys or menu click by that time :( but when your program is working that's different story

Comment: It's a little more subtle: LINQPad does its rendering and other time-consuming activities on cancelable worker threads, but at some point it must feed the resultant HTML to the embedded WebBrowser (a WinForms control). It's this final step that was causing the UI to freeze, in the case of large and complex HTML.

Answer (score 2):

Use task manager to kill the work process, doesn't work?

Comment: I'm sure that works :). And it seems to be the only solution. I was just thinking if there would be a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

As @Frank's answer indicated, the LinqPad GUI becomes unresponsive when it is rendering the HTML output of the `.Dump()` operation for display in the results panel.

I have already created a request on the LinqPad uservoice site ([here](https://linqpad.uservoice.com/forums/18302-linqpad-feature-suggestions/suggestions/5508662-cancel-long-running-dump-rendering)), to make this step in running a LinqPad query either cancel-able, or to process it on a background thread.

Feel free to add votes to this feature request to push it up the priority stack.